# Installing MuPDF on Linux for use with PHP

Tags: php, linux, mupdf

How would I go about building muPDF so I can use it with PHP through maybe exec?  I know this person has listed out instructions for installing onto linux at: https://neerajkarimpuzha.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/compiling-mupdf-from-source/

However, how would I go about setting it up so I can just do command line's to the compiled version from exec in php ?

Comment: Which part of the compilation do you have issues with? If you have the binary, install it on the system path, or run it from a relative directory `exec("./whatever");`

Comment: @mario whats the system path?  where is exec base directory located where i would need to put the compiled MuPDF for it to run from command line?

Comment: It's `$PATH` or whatever you set that to. Exec base directory is the current working directory, dirname of the invocation script. Or just use absolute paths.